# Serving some js/html files by php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, docker-compose

I have a setup of docker-compose having nginx and wordpress. I followed one of the tutorials across the web and everything seems to work fine.

BUT I have one critical plugin which generates a couple of html/js files directly via PHP. Meaning HTML code contains `<script>` tag with path to `/script.js`, plugin catches that particular name and respond with appropriate content. No url-rewrite modules involved here, only some self-written (i.e. from plugin)

I can't figure out how to configure nginx to allow fpm docker image to serve that server-side generated js.

Now  I have the following setup:

```
location / {
  try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
}
location ~ ^/(script1.js|script2.js) {
  fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
}
location ~* \.(css|js|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png)$ {
  expires max;
  log_not_found off;
}
```

Once I reaquest the page, script1 and script2 respond with 404.

Is this possible to achieve in general?

Comment: Just as a test, try removing both of the last two location blocks: `location ~ ^/(script1.js|script2.js)` and `location ~* \.(css|js|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png)$` and see if the site works correctly albeit with the wrong `expires` value.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply @RichardSmith. It is solves the issue but this means that any JS files will be serviced by fpm as well rather then serving them statically..

Comment: No, that means that all non-existent JS files will be served by `index.php`. See the `try_files` directive in your config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try_files` statement will serve static files if they exist and otherwise send the request to `/index.php`. Because the `script1.js` and `script2.js` files do not exist, they are handled by `/index.php`, which is what you want.

The `location ~ ^/(script1.js|script2.js)` and `location ~* \.(css|js|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png)$` blocks breaks this logic.

One solution is to remove the `location ~ ^/(script1.js|script2.js)` block (which is just wrong), and place a `try_files` statement into the `location ~* \.(css|js|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png)$` block.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    ...
}
location ~* \.(css|js|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png)$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}
```